# login_required doesn't work when redirecting

Tags: python, django

I have a function in my view which has a decorator `login_required`. When the user is not authenticated redirects me automatically to

```
babylon/?next=prot/ats2
```

but it should be:

```
babylon/prot/?next=prot/ats2
```

since `babylon/prot` is the root from my project (it is set up like that in my apache config).

`LOGIN_URL` seems not to apply for this problem.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: post some configs (urls, mostly)

Comment: what is your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` settings ?

Comment: @karthikr i don't have a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, but i was playing with it and it doesnt work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Django 1.5, you can [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url) can be the name of the url pattern. So if you have a url pattern named 'login', you should be able to do:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

If you're using Django 1.4, you can use `reverse_lazy`

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy 

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
```

If that doesn't work, you're probably going to have to update your question to include the relevant part of your apache config.

Comment: This is what I get: django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def my_view(request):
# ...
    my_view = login_required(redirect_field_name='redirect_to')(my_view)
```

Or you can also use:

```
settings.py
LOGIN_URL  = '/where/'
```

In documentation we can read that:

```
LOGIN_URL
Default: '/accounts/login/'

The URL where requests are redirected for login, especially when using the login_required() decorator.
```

I have no idea what it is not working.

Comment: redirect_field_name is just the name of the field, by default it is "next"

Comment: Yea you have right, I just checked that... Searching for other solution.